# Error message loading www.serverfault.com

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I just typed `http://www.serverfault.com` to my browser, and it shows an ASP error page. Is that correct behavior?

Comment: Short answer: no.
long answer: nooooooooooope

Comment: strange, it seem directed only to the homepage, as I just followed a reply, and it worked to go in the question. well the site work with serverfault.com, not www.serverfault.com

Comment: an update, they seem to have done a rewrite rule for www.serverfault.com >> serverfault.com to bypass the error.

Comment: Now `www.serverfault.com` works, but optimal would be 301 redirect to `serverfault.com`, if that is the preferred domain.